# Would a single obsidian blade produce more pressure compared to two obsidian blades?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, pressure

Suppose you have a blade made of obsidian with an area of $4 nm^2$ and applied a force of $20 N$. If there were two of the same blades with the same area and pressure applied against an object, would both blades produce $20 N/4nm^2$, or would each blade be halved in pressure?

Comment: The damage done by claws depends on the claw type, the animal's muscle and support structure and what it's hitting.  It's not really a simple physics problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer depends primarily on biological factors.

Comment: I don't think it needs to be closed. I'll edit my post so it could be a question regarding physics.

Comment: In the object, directly adjacent to each blade, the traction or pressure is $20\,\mathrm{N}/4\,\mathrm{nm}^2$, assuming static equilibrium, linear elasticity, etc.

Comment: So does this mean both blades are producing $20 N / 4 nm^2$ equally?

Comment: You say "the same pressure". So you already answered your question. If each blade applies the same pressure as before then the pressure is the same, of course.  You just apply the same pressure in two different areas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you apply the same force to area determined by two blades, which is $8nm^2$, so resulted pressure by definition $P = F/A$ will be twice lower than with one blade.

To get the same result from "blade's perspective": overall force pushes two blades, which is equivalent of each blade pushed by half force independently. So each blade is pushed by half force, but contacts the same area, so pressure is halved.

This effect is well known in bed of nails trick. If you lay on a single nail, you apply full weight to very small area and injury is inevitable. If you lay on two nails with the same weight, pressure is halved, but it isn't small enough. If you lay on 10 000 nails, pressure is divided by 10 000 and you're fine. Google videos of "bed of nails with baloon" for simple demonstration.